# На хостинге остаются Scss файлы, что же делать?

Tags: php, html, css, gulp

Залил свою верстку на хостинг, но при попытке изменить значения в style.css ничего не выходит! а в инспекторе кода указывает что стили прописаны в main.scss, хотя их вообще в папке нет ( я заливал только скомпилированный style.scss). 
Сам сайт написан на каком то генераторе шаблонов ( приложу код как это выглядит)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src={$url_site}/sources/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Сам сайт

http://102010.ru/

Изменил в style.css на display: block, но в инспекторе кода видно обращение к файлу main.scss

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вот скриншот из панели разработчика. Вот лежит файл main.scss и в файле style.scss он импортируется.
[image: Импорт]

Comment: я эти файлы туда не заливал 
вот всё что есть
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMuxf.png